# Reversing a string without two loops?

Tags: c

I came up with the following basic item to reverse a string in C:

```
void reverse(char in[], char out[]) {

    int string_length = 0;

    for(int i=0; in[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        string_length += 1;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < string_length ; i++) {
        out[string_length-i] = in[i];
    }
    out[string_length+1] = '\0';
}
```

Is there a way to do this in one `for` loop or is it necessary to first use a `for` length to get the string length, and then do a second one to reverse it? Are there other approaches to doing a `reverse`, or is this the basic one?

Comment: in the code given it should be `i < string_length` not `i <= string_length`

Comment: @RishikeshRaje -- I tried this but then it skips the first letter. Perhaps there's something instead that I'm doing strangely above?

Comment: "there's something instead that I'm doing strangely above?" --> post a [mcve]

Comment: @Shared I can't see why this is skipping the first letter by changing `<=` to `<` in the second loop.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje -- thanks for this suggestion. It was the `\0` character at the end. The string size I was doing did not include that character at the end.

Comment: for each character you find, push it on the stack, then once done, pop all from the stack.

Comment: Knowing the maximum size of `out` you could start copying at the end and go back, until `out` is full or you find `\0` in `in`.

Comment: @Alex Maximum size of `out` would not give the position where to start copying *from* in `in`. Getting length of `in` would still be required, and that requires a loop in C.

Comment: @hyde - in the original statement it was `out[string_length--1-i]` In this case for `string_length == i` you would get `out[-1]`

Comment: @hyde, `in` must start from the beginning. `out[maxout-i] = in[i++]`. But it only works if you know the `out` dimension

Comment: @Alex Consider case where `in` is empty string, and `maxout` is 20. Does it behave correclty?

Comment: @hyde It depends on whether he has to stick to that prototype function or can change it.

Comment: @Shared - Setting `out[string_length+1] = '\0'` is wrong. it should be `out[string_length] = '\0'` e.g. for the string "abcdefg" `string_length' is 7 and out[7] will be set to '\0' See the code https://www.onlinegdb.com/HyYHsl6NS

Comment: The obvious solution is to pass the size along with the parameters. The caller likely already have it stored, or is able to determine it at compile-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you can't use functions to get the string length *and* you want to preserve the second loop I'm afraid this is the shortest way.

Just as a side-note though: this code is not very safe as at `for(int i=0; in[i] != '\0'; i++)` you are not considering cases where the argument passed to parameter `in` is not a valid *C string* where there isn't a single `\0` in all elements of the array pointed by `in` and this code will end up manifesting a buffer over-read at the first `for loop` when it will read beyond `in` boundaries and a buffer overflow in the second `for loop` where you *can* write beyond the boundaries of `out`. In functions like this you should ask the caller for the length of both arrays `in` and `out` and use that as a *max index* when accessing them both.

As pointed by Rishikesh Raje in comments: you should also change the *exit condition* in the second for loop from `i <= string_length` to `i < string_length` as it will generate another buffer over-read when `i == string_length` as it will access `out` by a negative index.

Answer (score 3):

```
void reverse(char *in, char *out) {

    static int index;
    index = 0;

    if (in == NULL || in[0] == '\0')
    {
        out[0] = '\0';
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        reverse(in + 1, out);
        out[index + 1] = '\0';
        out[index++] = in[0];
    }
}
```

With no loops.

This code is surely not efficient and robust and also won't work for multithreaded programs. Also the OP just asked for an alternative method and the stress was on methods with lesser loops.

> Are there other approaches to doing a reverse, or is this the basic one

Also, there was no real need of using `static int`. This would cause it not to work with multithreaded programs. To get it working correct in those cases:

```
int reverse(char *in, char *out) {

    int index;

    if (in == NULL || in[0] == '\0')
    {
        out[0] = '\0';
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        index = reverse(in + 1, out);
        out[index + 1] = '\0';
        out[index++] = in[0];
        return index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works just once, as `index` is never reset. Doesn't work if `in` is empty.

Comment: Also, mentioning memory use and risk of stack overflow with linear recursion depth would be good...

Comment: Also to note: if you have this function being executed in parallel on more than 1 thread you can have race conditions on variable `index`.

Comment: Well, this is a much worse alternative than loops. The machine code at `gcc -O3` looks horrible - it tries to inline and tail call optimize, but you get hundreds of instructions. Bad idea.

Comment: @hyde, thnx for pointing that out, I didn't notice. I have made corrections to my answer.

Comment: @dedecos, check the updated answer, I posted an alternative.

Comment: @Lundin, that's for sure, but this question just asks for alternatives.

Comment: @Mihir actually OP asked for a possible solution without both for loops, implying the second one should be used. Nice insight though.

Answer (score 1):

You can always tweak two loops into one, more confusing version, by using some kind of condition to determine which phase in the algorithm you are in. Below code is untested, so most likely contains bugs, but you should get the idea...

```
void reverse(const char *in, char *out) {

    if (*in == '\0') {
        // handle special case
        *out = *in;
        return;
    }

    char *out_begin = out;
    char *out_end;
    do {
        if (out == out_begin) {
            // we are still looking for where to start copying from
            if (*in != '\0') {
                // end of input not reached, just go forward
                ++in;
                ++out_end;
                continue;
            }
            // else reached end of input, put terminating NUL to out
            *out_end = '\0';
        }
        // if below line seems confusing, write it out as 3 separate statements.
        *(out++) = *(--in);
    } while (out != out_end); // end loop when out reaches out_end (which has NUL already)
}
```

However, this is exactly as many loop iterations so it is not any faster, and it is much less clear code, so don't do this in real code...